# Query to find count of tagging for item in column A to item in column B

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I need to find out count of different entries for same entry in a column (State - North Dakota) to another column (Onshore, offshore) in SQL. In the attached sample - Number of mismatch is 1 (North Dakota - Offshore). Many thanks for any help.

.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to count the number of `state`s that have more than 1 distinct `terrain`. If so, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*) no_mismatches
from (select state from mytable group by state having min(state) <> max(state)) t
```

Comment: Thanks GMB - Just one more help please. If there are multiple states, how can I get count for only North Dakota. Thanks again

Comment: @Nishant: do you want `where state = 'North Dakota'` in the subquery?

Comment: Yeah - Where can I use it in the code to give me the count of mismatches in North Dakota only.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `count(distinct)`?

```
select state, count(distinct terrain)
from t
group by state;
```